# finding master view controller in xcode 12 beta

Tags: xcode, xcode12, xcode12beta6

I was attempting to create a master detail application. With the older Xcode versions this was possible for me. But with the Xcode 12 beta, I was unable to find anything but Application, Game, document app, swift package, In-app purchase content, Empty and external build system. So if someone can help me find or explain to me why or why the Master-Detail Application is not listed. Thanks for any help.